# How to render a react component using HTML class attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I tried following but it seems not working. Is this possible to render a react component using HTML class?

**HTML**

```
<div class="appKlass"> 
</div>
```

**JSX**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h3>Hello Universe</h3>,
  document.getElementsByClassName("appKlass")
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object ([HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)) of html elements. But `render` needs a DOM node as the second argument. So you have to give an index to what returned by `getElementsByClassName` and get a specific element from the array.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h3>Hello Universe</h3>,
  document.getElementsByClassName("appKlass")[0]
)
```

Comment: Yes, it works. I thought  React could render a component to multiple html elements like with the same class name `appKlass`. Lot to learn. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would be cleaner to use `document.querySelector('.appKlass')`. This will return a single DOM element or null. In case there are multiple `.appKlass` in the page, it will return the first one.